# Atmosphere failure with "Failure of Web Server bridge"

Tags: apache, jms, weblogic, atmosphere

Atmosphere requests to /push started getting the following response after some time(1min):

Session time out

```
 <HTML>
   <HEAD>
      <TITLE>Weblogic Bridge Message</TITLE>
   </HEAD>
   <BODY>
      <H2>Failure of Web Server bridge:</H2>
      <P>
      <hr>
      <PRE>Internal Server Failure. Cannot Continue.</PRE>
      <hr>
   </BODY>
</HTML>
```

We are using:

```
atmosphere version=2.2.1
atmosphere client javascript version=2.2.6
atmosphere runtime version=2.2.4
weblogic version=12.1.1

Apache server
```

Comment: Fixed. Was caused by timeout not properly configured for atmosphere

Answer (score 0):

Fixed. Was caused by timeout not properly configured for atmosphere